# Underscore JS: get 5 items per category

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I would like to have just 5 items per category. Let's say I have an array like this:

```
[
  {product_name: "test", supplier: "1"}
  {product_name: "test", supplier: "1"}
  {product_name: "test", supplier: "1"}
  {product_name: "test", supplier: "1"}
  {product_name: "test", supplier: "1"}
  {product_name: "test", supplier: "1"}
  {product_name: "test", supplier: "2"}
  {product_name: "test", supplier: "2"}
  {product_name: "test", supplier: "2"}
  {product_name: "test", supplier: "3"}
  {product_name: "test", supplier: "3"}
  {product_name: "test", supplier: "3"}
  {product_name: "test", supplier: "3"}  
]
```

Of each supplier I would like to have the first 5 products. 
I don't have a clue how to do that. Someone has?

My current code:

```
var formattedProducts = _(products).map( function( product ) {

    var pr =  product.dataValues;
    var endTime = pr.end_datetime;

    return pr;
});
```

Comment: You mean something like `groupBy(supplier).map(slice(0, 5))`?

Comment: added demo for answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me

```
var data = [
  {product_name: "test", supplier: "1"},
  {product_name: "test", supplier: "1"},
  {product_name: "test", supplier: "1"},
  {product_name: "test", supplier: "1"},
  {product_name: "test", supplier: "1"},
  {product_name: "test", supplier: "1"},
  {product_name: "test", supplier: "2"},
  {product_name: "test", supplier: "2"},
  {product_name: "test", supplier: "2"},
  {product_name: "test", supplier: "3"},
  {product_name: "test", supplier: "3"},
  {product_name: "test", supplier: "3"},
  {product_name: "test", supplier: "3"}  
]
```

**1)** First group by all elements according to supplier.

**2)** Get each group get their first 5 elements & con-cat to result array.

```
var result = [];
var groups = _.groupBy(data,function (item) {
    return item.supplier;
}); 

_.each(groups,function(value){
    result = result.concat(_.first(value,5));
})

console.log(result);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/qvwpp/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, here's a Lo-Dash chained style version.

```
var result = _(products)
    .groupBy('supplier')
    .map(function (productsBySupplier) {
        return _.first(productsBySupplier, 5)
    })
    .flatten()
    .value()
```